Keep getting error when trying to install packages from terminal
I want to download the finch package but keep getting this type of error which I think is a dependency issue
pip install finch

Collecting finch
  Using cached finch-0.3.3.tar.gz (5.0 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting tornado<3.2 (from finch)
  Using cached tornado-3.1.1.tar.gz (374 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting booby<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 (from finch)
  Using cached booby-0.4.0.tar.gz (7.2 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in booby setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

This error keeps happening whenever I've tried to install a package over the last month or so. Is there any way to make sure this doesn't keep happening again and again ?
Can I remove and re-install all packages I have installed and can it help resolve this issue ?
I there some kind of doc that lists dependencies and which package versions will work with others ?
THANK YOU!
SOLUTION: So this error usually occurs when trying to install packages that are no longer maintained and end up throwing dependency issues. Installed finch-clust and it works fine

Does this answer your question? Error in anyjson setup command: use_2to3 is invalid
